Intermittent vibrations
2015 CX-5 FWD @ 185k miles. I owned it since 180k miles (dont have history).
PROBLEM:
Vibrations at low speeds can be recreated all the time:
Loading the engine (accelerate from a stop) AND

Going straight feels like a minor vibration in the wheel
Turning right feels like a "torque wobble" or something tugging at the wheel at the rate of transmission speed.
Felt through chassis and steering wheel.

Vibration at HIGH speed is INTERMITTENT:
With increasing speed -> increasing potential steering wheel vibrations.
Feels like a wheel imbalance. But the intermittent nature does not agree.
I tested this on a 400 mile road trip and vibrations seem to be more related to road conditions than anything else.
Troubleshooting:
There are no sounds like clicks, knocks or rattles that can be heard.

Highway driving when vibration present -> switch gears, go into neutral: Very subtle improvement, if at all.
No play in the wheels when testing by hand.
Rotate wheels, replace tires and rims -> no improvement
Replace engine mount that looked torn -> unrelated improvements
Front brake calipers, rotors and pads all new -> unrelated improvements
Control arm bushings have minimal play, but seem original with signs of aging.
Wheel bearings are smooth with 0 play.
Replace drivers side Axle with Low mileage OEM replacement -> Subjective improvement, problem still existed!

Note: All CV axles had no play in any of the joints when they cooled down. When things were warm, i can feel some radial play between the shaft and the inner joint(on both OEM drivers side axles).
There seems to be a lot of play when things warm up between the inner joint and the transmission on the drivers side, but i have no metric to know what is excessive.
Any help is appreciated!
Thanks,
Phil.

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!
